# How can I pass a command line argument which contains space character to my C++ program?

Tags: c++, whitespace, argv, dev-c++, argc

We can access command line arguments via `argv` code in C++, I know that.

But the problem is, if an argument contains space, then my program works like as if there are two parameters.

For example if the argument is `foo bar`, my program sees two parameters (`foo` and `bar`).

Here is my code:

`string strParameter = string(argv[1]);`

So, what should I do?

Comment: Typically you need to put it in quotes. Details may depend on the OS you are using.

Comment: There's only a handful of applications that I know that will attempt to intelligently parse a command line for arguments that aren't in quotes that should be. Notepad is one example.  But the other 99.9% of programs rely on the caller to pass `"foo bar"` in quotes.  Just optimize for the user to correctly invoke your program with arguments in quotes as needed. No one will complain.

Comment: A specific case: If there are no other args after the filename, and if the quotes around the filename are not expected, then why not iterate over the `argv`'s with `argc` as the limit and append to your string?

Comment: On Windows, you can call `GetCommandLine` to obtain the raw command line before splitting into `argv`.

Answer (score 5):

This is determined by your shell, not your program. In most shells, you can solve this either by wrapping the parameter in single and/or double quotes:

- `"foo bar"`
- `'foo bar'`

or putting a special symbol before the space:

- `foo\ bar`
- `foo^ bar` in CMD (on Windows)

Comment: I mean, I have written a C++ program which gets a file as an argument. But the problem is the file's name contains space character.

Comment: @DrakeMcCain I understand, you said it in the question.

Comment: The first one, `"foo bar"` is universal on Windows, Mac, and Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have fixed my problem myself.

Here is my solution:

```
for(int i=1; i<argc; i++)
{
    strParameter = strParameter + string(argv[i]) + " ";
}
```

Comment: Unlike quotes, this doesn't let you pass *several* arguments with spaces. Also it incorrectly treats 2+ spaces as single space.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat My program does not already get more then one argument. So, it is ok for me.

Comment: There will be a trailing space at the end of the loop. If the argument is a file name for example, it won't work.